# Configure FileAppender after Log4j2 Initialization

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm having trouble configuring a new `FileAppender` for my `log4j2` logger. The problem is that I only know the path of the file I should be appending my log **after** the application starts, so I tried following these instructions [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#AddingToCurrent) for modifying the original configuration after `log4j2` is initialized.

I've read a lot of answers regarding similar issues on stack overflow but most of them are for earlier `log4j` versions, and won't work as they have now implemented that configuration oriented plugin into log4j itself.

The app **successfuly creates the log file but it won't write any content to it**. I've put that test log message on `ERROR` level on purpose so I could verify it wasn't any issue related to the log level threshold or something.

I'm kind of new to log4j2 configuration and feeling a bit lost at this point.

My `log4j2.xml` file (very basic) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
             <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Also, here's the method that should be adding that new `FileAppender`:

```
public static void initLogFile(String path, Level level) {
    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
    Layout layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout(config);
    Appender appender = FileAppender.createAppender(path, "false", "true",
            "RollingFile", "true", "false", "false", "8000", null, null,
            "false", null, config);
    appender.start();
    config.addAppender(appender);
    AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("RollingFile", null,
            null);
    AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] { ref };
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger("false", level,
            "org.apache.logging.log4j", "true", refs, null, config, null);
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
    config.addLogger("org.apache.logging.log4j", loggerConfig);
    ctx.updateLoggers();
    System.out.println("Logger initialized");
}
```

And my `Main` method, which the very first thing it does is try to change the logger config to write into the file I want:

```
static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
  public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // Init
        System.out.println("Initializing logger");
        Utils.initLogFile("C:/Users/Jorge/Desktop/logtest/test.log", Level.DEBUG);

        log.error("test error message");

        ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm accepting this answer because its related **strictly** to the question's title. If you're checking this post for help you should take a moment to read @rgoers answer as it might be what you're looking for.

So here's how I finally did it. Configuring an existing empty new logger into my `log4j2.xml` file (as I didn't want to create a new one on runtime) which I would modify on runtime.

The issue with my original code was the logger's name. If you take a look at the original post I was creating a new appender named "org.apache.logging.log4j".

On my main class when I retrieved the logger with which I was going to log, I was getting the default's logger for the package in which my main class is (`com.jorge.myapp.business`). Thus, this logger was receiving all the log requests and the new one I created (`org.apache.logging.log4j`) wasn't receiving any. That's why it wouldn't log anything to the file I inteded it to, because all logging requests where going to other logger (`com.jorge.myapp.business`).

I hope this helps somebody, it's a bit confusing to explain... Below more info about my classes and config file:

Modified **config** file `log4j2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
             <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="com.jorge.myapp.business" level="debug">
        </Logger>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is the **initializing method**, it retrieves the current `log4j2` config from the xml file and modifies the existing logger adding a new file appender

```
public static void initLogFile(String path, Level level){

    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();

    Layout layout = PatternLayout.createLayout(Constants.LOG_PATTERN, null, config, null, null, false, false, null, null);
    Appender appender = FileAppender.createAppender(path, "true", "true", "File", "true",
        "false", "false", null, layout, null, "false", null, config);
    appender.start();
    config.addAppender(appender);
    AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("File", null, null);
    AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] {ref};
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig("com.jorge.myapp.business");
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
    ctx.updateLoggers();
}
```

Some **constants** I used (`Constants.java` class):

```
public static final String LOG_PATTERN = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5level] MyApp - %msg%n";
```

More info about how Log4j2 actually works 'under the hood' can be found [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html), as pointed out by @rgoers.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean that you only know the path after the application starts?  No matter what, you should always be able to use a Lookup to determine the file path. If the path is specified as one of the arguments to the application you should be able to use the main arguments lookup.

To be clear, your configuration should something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
<Properties>
    <Property name="PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
         <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="file" fileName="${main:--logFile}">
         <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN}"/>
    </File> 
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.apache.logging.log4j" level="${main:--level}">
       <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Note that I have configured a File appender. Your sample code is creating a File appender but is naming it "RollingFile" for some reason.

Comment: One of the app's arguments is that log file path. When any user runs the app via command line, the path to the file which will contain all the log generated by the app (its actually a runnable JAR) is passed by as an argument. Im not having trouble finding the file, Im having trouble writing into a dinamycally configured `FileAppender`

Comment: Don't dynamically configure the file appender. Add it to the configuration file.  Just use ${main:--file} or whatever the option is for the file to get the file path.  If, for some reason, that doesn't work for you you can created your own lookup.  But there is no good reason I can think of to programmatically configure the appender based on your description.

Comment: Maybe my way of doing it isn't the best and you're right, I should be using the configuration you suggest, but I'm curious to know why the log file in which the appender I created should write into is empty at the end of the app execution... What am I misunderstanding about the creation of the new file appender? It isn't logging anything and I don't know why. Nevertheless I'll try to work it out as you suggest, but I'd like to understand why my approach doesn't work

Comment: Probably because the LoggerConfig you are creating is named org.apache.logging.log4j.  Are you actually creating any loggers under that package? It is highly doubtful.

Comment: Indeed, that was it! The problem was with the `org.apache.logging.log4j`. Changing it to one of my app packages that send requests to the logger did the trick and wrote into the file.. I still don't understand what has to do the name of the logger with the package but if you can explain in another answer I'll accept it as it's the solution I was asking for.

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment, but I guess the issue with the name is explained here at the bottom: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/api.html

Comment: Actually, http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html should explain this in detail.  I am happy you got it working but the recommended approach for others would be to follow the example I posted above.

Comment: Indeed, I've updated my answer with your reference to the Log4j2 docs and I'll accept it, as it answers the original question's title. I've also edited my answer in case someone checks it in the future and could read your answer too and see if it fits his/her needs. Thanks for your time!